# Remove useless keys from vscode.ExtensionContext.globalState

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been working on some extension for visual studio code. Once I have finished I wanted to clean up the global state I have used but I couldn't find a way to do it. I running the extension in debug, in watch I can find all the old keys.

The API provided for `vscode.ExtensionContext.globalState` has only two methods: `update` and `get`.

What I wish to do is to find a way to remove the key, not only clear the value.

Could you be so kind and advise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Setting the value to `undefined` will result in next debug iteration that the key will be deleted from `globalState._value` object.

```
context.globalState.update('testkey', undefined).then(function () {
            console.log(context.globalState.get('testkey'));
        });
```

Solution found on [github vscode repository page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11528).